# ¿Cómo puedo corregir "ERROR: invalid US-ASCII character "\xC3" "en Prepos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo esto en HAML

```
%html{class:"no-js", lang:"es"}
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}
    %title La mejor comida.
    %meta{name:"description", content:"Come rico en el mejor restaurante de la ciudad, servicio de primera."}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/normalize.css"}
    %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/style.css"}
    %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
    %script{src:"js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"}
  %body
    ="<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
        %p{class:"browserupgrade"}
        Estas úsando un navegador 
        %strong desactualizado. 
        Por favor 
        %a{href:"http://browsehappy.com/"}
        actualiza tu navegador 
        para una mejor experiencia.
    ="<![endif]-->"
    .video-container 
        %video{autoplay:true,loop:true,width:"1280",height:"720",poster:"/"}
            /Cambiar Videos, Poner el poster                      
            %source{src:"/videos/mp4/cambiar.mp4",typ:"video/mp4"}
```

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser la "ú", la cual por otra parte no necesita tilde en la palabra "usando". En tu caso no hay ninguna otra letra no-ascii, pero para una solución más general, deberías especificar de alguna forma el "encoding" del fichero, ya que aparentemente ruby lo está considerando ascii y falla ante un caracter no-ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer ese es un problema de prepos.
A tu archivo `config.ru` agrégale:

```
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: En que parte lo agrego al inicio o al final del archivo?

Comment: ¿por? ¿probaste ambos y no te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Para mi funciono actualizar la versión:

```
sudo gem update
```

Y luego:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```